# Pandas - Aggregating and Ploting data from multiplefiles

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple files naming like starting with Quarter'Year prefix like "Q121", "Q222" and all of these files contains data like below, Identifier stays the same but price and power columns are chainging. What would be the best way to aggregate files and be able to plot column like price across data range e.g from Q1'20 to Q2'22.

I was thinking about merging different files based on Identifier and then change column names to reflect Q120 etc...

```
data = [['A1', 10,50], ['A2', 15,60], ['A3', 14,55]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Identifier', 'Price','Power'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from glob import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob("target_folder/*.csv")
dfs = []
for file_path in files:
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
    temp = pd.read_csv(file_path, names=["Price","Power"], header=None)
    temp["Identifier"] = file_name.replace(".csv", "")
    dfs.append(temp)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
# change Q122 -> 22Q1, so the plot can order full list nicely 
df["Identifier"] = df["Identifier"].apply(lambda x: "".join([x[2],x[3],x[0],x[1]]))
```

Comment: Thanks, works good so far - now how i can plot for specific identifier column Price?

Comment: My Identifier columns looks like below: 21Q3 22Q2 21Q2 22Q1 21Q4, so in wrong order

Comment: you could do 
df = df.sort_values(by="Identifier")